# Static .json files are not loaded while running Ionic Framework application on smartphone

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following files in the “…/assets/strings/” directory of my Ionic application:

```
“…/assets/strings/pt-br.json”;
“…/assets/strings/es-es.json”;
“…/assets/strings/pt-br.json”
```

When I run my application in the browser, with the “ionic serve” command, these files are perfectly accessed.

[image: Working in browser1]

[image: Json file loaded in build]

However, when I run on the smartphone with the “ionic cordova run android” command, .json files are not copied to the “android_asset / www” directory, and therefore are not accessed in the application that is running on the smartphone. Causing the following error:

[image: Cell phone malfunction]
[image: Failed to load json file on mobile]

Any tip will be very welcome, as I have already lost a few hours with this problem.

Very frustrating that something, which should apparently be trivial, is not easily achieved.

Here are new prints to improve understanding of the problem
[image]
[image]

Comment: does it work if you change var url to `var url = "assets/strings/yourfile.json";`

Comment: @reiner.luke mostly correct i have this issue with ionic it mostly need to be assest/etc..//

Comment: Yeah the files get moved around a bit when building the app. You cant refer to assets relatively ... do what @reiner.luke said and make it an absolute path src='assets/strings/yourfile.json'

Comment: Even changing the path to "assets / strings / en-br.json", I still have the same problem.
I can not find files with the .json extension, while browsing the directories, in the application running on the phone, so I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but it does not seem to be a url problem.
Apparently the build process is simply ignoring .json files.
One attempt I made was to include the following statement "" src / assets / strings / *. Json "" in the "include" section in the "tsconfig.json" file, just below the src / ** / *. Ts ",", but this also did not result in expected behavior.